# how to enable php-pgsql driver on AWS lightsail for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services

**===== Background (you can skip!)**

I am trying to build my wordpress website on AWS lightsail. I want to connect my site to Postgresql via plugin(wpDataTables), so i tried installing php-pgsql driver.
I followed every step (sudo apt-get install php-pgsql, edit php.ini and restart the server) but the driver is NOT enabled when i check phpinfo();.

This is strange because i can check the driver is installed via terminal, but whenever i try to do something related to php, it gives my this error :

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_pgsql' (tried: /opt/bitnami/
> php/lib/php/extensions/pdo_pgsql (/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php/extensions/pdo_pgsql: cannot ope
> n shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/bitnami/php/lib/php/extensions/pdo_p
> gsql.so (/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php/extensions/pdo_pgsql.so: cannot open shared object file:
> No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pgsql' (tried: /opt/bitnami/php/
> lib/php/extensions/pgsql (/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php/extensions/pgsql: cannot open shared obj
> ect file: No such file or directory), /opt/bitnami/php/lib/php/extensions/pgsql.so (/opt/bi
> tnami/php/lib/php/extensions/pgsql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or dire
> ctory)) in Unknown on line 0

I was frustrated, and when I raised this issue to the WpdataTables support team, they said it's the hosting provider's problem (?)

THEN I tried the same thing on AWS EC2, not on lightsail. I did not go through the whole procedure (because I didn't want to create RDS) but I checked that php-pgsql is properly installed and enabled in this way.

**===== Question**

My question is, is there anyone who succeeded to enable php-pgsql driver on aws lightsail for wordpress? I was able to install it via terminal, but it is not "enabled" (i checked via phpinfo();)
I was able to do the same thing on AWS EC2, so i think this issue is related to lightsail.

Comment: cant you just install it via terminal? apt-get install php-pgsql

Comment: Hello, yes i installed via terminal using the same command, and i can check it is "installed" but sadly it is not enabled when i checked via phpinfo(); (under pdo tap)

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue ? I ask cause I'm stuck at the same place.

Comment: @YannieB I was't abled to do this in lightsail eventually, so I moved my site to EC2 instance. Worked perfectly with same command line... :)